# Django Admin Interface Add Filter on Foreign Key

Tags: django, key, admin

I am using Django 1.2.3, and am attempting to add a list filter on a foreign key.

It seems that the '__' syntax does not work in this version.

The best solution I could find seemed to be implementing a filterspec:
http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2194/

I could not get this to work, and even went so far to create a very simple app based on this sample model, to no avail.

In addition to the code listed above, my admin.py includes:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from data.models import *

class companyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('name', 'city')
        #list_filter = ('name', 'name')
        #list_filter = ('name', 'Country')
        #list_filter = ('name', 'country')
        list_filter = ('name', 'city__country')
        #list_filter = ('name', 'city.country')
        #list_filter = ('name', 'city.fk_filterspec')
        #list_filter = ('name', 'fk_filterspec')


admin.site.register(Country)
admin.site.register(City)
admin.site.register(Company, companyAdmin)
```

Is this the best solution?

Any suggestions on how to make this sample work?

The error I get is "'companyAdmin.list_filter[1]' refers to field 'city__country' that is missing from model 'Company'".

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: is there a reason you are developing in such an old/unsupported version of Django?

Comment: Good question! The site is running on a Debian server (squeeze), and this is the package provided by the package manager. While I may be able to get this updated, there is some concern what the imact would be to other projects running on this server so at this point I am working with what I have...

Comment: you should be using virtualenv on the server that way your application's packages can be separate from any other applications.

Comment: Interesting... I was not familiar with virtualenv, and will have to take a look. I don't have full control over the server as it is a shared resource, but this may be an option. If it is not, any other suggestions?

Comment: I started django dev on django 1.3 so im not extremely well versed in 1.2 workarounds

Comment: We went ahead an updated django, which did requiring a little re-factoring, but the issue is resolved.